# Github Pages Not Loading CSS Background Image

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I am working on a project to copy a static website for practice. Here is the [original](https://www.kastapp.co/).

My copy is hosted here on [Github pages](https://artemsgithub.github.io/staticLayoutProject/).

As you can see, the original has an abstract background image. When running my site on live-server, the background shows up with no issue. However, on Github the background does not show up, even though my directory structure did not change when I pushed it.

Here is the CSS that enables the background image, and works fine locally:

```css
background-image: url('/copy-site/assets/gradient-violet-bg.jpg');
```

Does Github not permit this sort of linking? If so, what is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that all the other images are correctly loaded in your site. I sudjest you to move the background image in the folder with the other images ( becouse now is not present) and put that url in the `background-image` property. So something like this

```
background-image: url('assets/gradient-violet-bg.jpg');
```

and should work. Another way wold be to call directly url of the image from the source website

```
background-image: url('https://www.kastapp.co/images/gradient-violet-bg.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the relative URL as `background-image: url("./assets/gradient-violet-bg.jpg")` and it will work.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)